# Flat rate in Shopping cart price rules by product ID or SKU

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have a category (**id 37**) for which I have already created a *Shopping Cart Price Rule* as followed:

( Free Shipping:  **if category id 37** *AND* **products in cart are 5 or more**)

Now what I need is, I have some of the products in this category for which I need to apply shopping rule as followed:

( Flat $8 Shipping price: **if category id is 37** *AND* **product id is one of [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]** *AND* **products in cart are 1 or more**)

**Note**: The second condition mentioned is for one category. There are other category's specific products too for which I need some other Flat rate added to shipping cost.

Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create a rule where you specify that it shouldn't apply for certain SKUs. See picutre below. This will give you free shipping. However, it doesn't set the shipping cost to 8 USD. As far as I know, there is no rule that will set the shipping to a certain amount else than free.

Three options I can think of:

- Use a fixed discount. Lets say your shipping is 50 USD. If the
  condition is true (5 +, in the category and not one of the selected
  SKUs), deduct fixed 50. If it is one of the 8 USD products, deduct
  only 42.
- Set the shipping amount to 8 USD for the complete store. The rule will not apply.
- Develop a module, and add an attribute, such as "special-shipping", use that attribute to assign a higher rate
  shipping.
- Get a plugin / module for Magento, such as e.g. https://amasty.com/shipping-rules.html.

[image: Image showing how to create rules]

Comment: But I need to add flat $8 for my second rule along with what ever rate comes from first rule

Comment: As stated in the answer and as far as I'm aware, this is not possible with shopping cart rules or any rules. You will have to use a module or take any of the two other approaches mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Please check the note added. I can add flat rate to whole cart as it can be varied for other category's products.

Comment: I'm quite sure this cannot be done without a plugin / module. I edited above to give example of such plugin.

Comment: Yes, a module is the right way to achieve so much customization. Thanks for all your suggestions.